# Image classification using SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

i'm using opencv SVM and i want to know if it is possible to know which image is closer to our input image instead of the class which the image belongs

Comment: Do you have any example or any code? what do you mean by class of image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean which training image? Using an SVM, the short answer is no. The SVM builds a model used for classification and it doesn't contain all the training images, just support vectors. Maybe NN is better suited to your problem.

Comment: I am currently working on a project where I have to extract the facial expression from an image. I've extracted the landmarks, now i want to classify the emotions + get the closest image's landmarks. So is there a possibility to do the classification based on the facial landmarks using nearest neighbour classification ?